# VB.net Strange Conditional Statement (IF)

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

Was wondering if someone could lend me their expertise. Pretty new to Vb.net and have come across this conditional statement in one of our products. Could someone please confirm the validity of the statement and explain what's going on here? I've tried numerous searches, but I cannot find anything related.

```
If (IsDBNull(dr("someID")), "0", dr("someID")) = someID.ToString() Then
```

I have changed the "id" value names as it's code from a commercial product, but the ID's used were all the same variable (ints).

Thanks for any input you can offer on this!

Joe

PS: The reason I can't check this at run time is because of how the product operates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an inline If statement
`If(condition,iftrue,iffalse)` if `condition` is true evaluate and return `iftrue` else `iffalse`

Comment: Doh! *facepalm* Thanks mate, that has saved me a huge mess!

Answer (score 1):

The `If operator` in VB.NET 2008 acts as a `ternary operator`.[ **[REFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx)**]

**Example:**

```
Dim foo as String = If(bar = buz, cat, dog) 'Condition satisfied then it'll return cat else dog.
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement is checking to see if the `dr("SomeID")` equals the value `someID.ToString`. The reason the If is required is because you need to check if the `dr("someID")` Is `Null`. If it is 0 is used instead which presumably should not be equal to `someID`.

It is the same as doing the following:

```
If Not IsDBNull(dr("someID")) Then
    If dr("someID").ToString = someID.ToString Then

    End If
End If
```

I would suggest that something like this would be more appropriate (checking integer values instead of comparing strings)

```
If(IsDBNull(dr("someID")), 0, CInt(dr("someID"))) = someID Then
```

I would also suggest Turning `Option Strict On` as the code you posted should not compile!